# Can't optimize loops with Loop unrolling without losing my output

Tags: c, loops, optimization, parallel-processing, loop-unrolling

I'm trying to optimize this function to its limits using loop unrolling techniques, but I can't figure out why my approach modifies my output (matrix "a") from the original function.

Right now I'm trying to step in 2 on each loop. Can anyone help me with this?
(This is a C++ program taken from git/FoleyLab/MolecularDynamics/ that is a simple molecular dynamics program for simulating real gas properties of Lennard-Jones particles)

**Original function:
**

```
void computeAccelerations()
{
    int i, j, k;
    double f, rSqd, rSqd4, rSqd7;
    double result1, result2, result3;
    double rij[3]; // position of i relative to j

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = 0;
        a[i][1] = 0;
        a[i][2] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            result1 = r[i][0] - r[j][0];
            result2 = r[i][1] - r[j][1];
            result3 = r[i][2] - r[j][2];
            rSqd = result1 * result1 + result2 * result2 + result3 * result3;

            rSqd4 = rSqd * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;
            rSqd7 = rSqd4 * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;

            f = 24 * (2 / rSqd7 - 1 / rSqd4);

            a[i][0] += result1 * f;
            a[j][0] -= result1 * f;
            a[i][1] += result2 * f;
            a[j][1] -= result2 * f;
            a[i][2] += result3 * f;
            a[j][2] -= result3 * f;
        }
    }
}
```

**My approach:
**

```
void computeAccelerations()
{
    int i, j, k;
    double f, rSqd, rSqd4, rSqd7;
    double result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6;
    double rij[6]; // position of i relative to j

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = 0;
        a[i][1] = 0;
        a[i][2] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i += 2)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j += 2)
        {
            result1 = r[i][0] - r[j][0];
            result2 = r[i][1] - r[j][1];
            result3 = r[i][2] - r[j][2];
            rSqd = result1 * result1 + result2 * result2 + result3 * result3;

            rSqd4 = rSqd * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;
            rSqd7 = rSqd4 * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;

            f = 24 * (2 / rSqd7 - 1 / rSqd4);

            a[i][0] += result1 * f;
            a[j][0] -= result1 * f;
            a[i][1] += result2 * f;
            a[j][1] -= result2 * f;
            a[i][2] += result3 * f;
            a[j][2] -= result3 * f;

            result4 = r[i + 1][0] - r[j + 1][0];
            result5 = r[i + 1][1] - r[j + 1][1];
            result6 = r[i + 1][2] - r[j + 1][2];
            rSqd = result4 * result4 + result5 * result5 + result6 * result6;

            rSqd4 = rSqd * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;
            rSqd7 = rSqd4 * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd;

            f = 24 * (2 / rSqd7 - 1 / rSqd4);

            a[i + 1][0] += result4 * f;
            a[j + 1][0] -= result4 * f;
            a[i + 1][1] += result5 * f;
            a[j + 1][1] -= result5 * f;
            a[i + 1][2] += result6 * f;
            a[j + 1][2] -= result6 * f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You changed the outer loop, but didn't duplicate the inner loop. There's also the odd-even corner cases that you need to cover.

Comment: If `N` is a compile-time constant, then compilers like Clang and ICC already unroll the code by default. In such a case, it is a bad idea to manually unroll the loop, simply because it makes the code less readable, harder to maintain and often introduce nasty bugs, not to mention it can slow things down since it is a bit more difficult for compilers to vectorize the loop in some cases (involving the SLP vectorization). If `N` is not a compile-time constant, you can unroll the loop with an additional inner loop using a compile-time constant. Besides, some compilers have `pragma` for that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard gcc is not as good as you think https://godbolt.org/z/eEvYqxqaT

Comment: What are the compilation flags? Note that `rSqd * rSqd * rSqd * rSqd` can be made faster using `(rSqd * rSqd) * (rSqd * rSqd)` without fast-math optimizations (same for `rSqd7`). Similarly, `24 * (2 / rSqd7 - 1 / rSqd4)` can be replaced with `(24 * 2) / rSqd7 - 24 / rSqd4`. Finally, storing data with the `(x, y, z)` memory layout is inefficient. It prevent SIMD optimizations which are far more important than unrolling. Please consider using a SIMD-friendly layout (like 3 arrays : one for each component).

Comment: @0___________ Yeah GCC is bad for unrolling. This is a well-known issue lasting since a while... This is why I did not mention it in the above comment. This is sad since GCC is quite often used in HPC when ICC is not... Anyway, I do not expect a significant speed up on modern x86-64 machine using unrolling here. A quick check confirms this expectation on Skylake using the GCC : both FMA units and the uops issue are the bottleneck. Thus, unrolling the code will not fix the FMA bottleneck and results in a very small speed-up. Using Clang, unrolling help a bit but not much (<15%).

Comment: @JérômeRichard The compiling flags that I'm using is -Ofast only. Thank you for your advises. Don't know much about vectorization but, will see!

Comment: Ok. `-Ofast` is basically `-O3` + `-ffast-math`. Thus, the above math-based optimizations should be already done by the compiler. On relatively-recent x86-64 CPU (eg. <10 years), `-mfma` may improve performance a bit. If your code is SIMD-friendly, the compiler will often auto-vectorize the code for you. Using `-mavx` (and even `-mavx2`), improve the performance of SIMD-friendly codes (only SSE is used by default). AVX can compute 4x item/instruction. If you do not know what is supported by your machine and you do not care about portability of the binaries, then you can use `-march=native`.